# How to secure login and member area with SSL certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

**Background**: I have a asp.net webapplication project that should contain a public and a member area. Now I want to implement a SSL decription to secure communication between the client and the server. (In the university we have an unsecured wireless network and you can use a wlan sniffer to read username/password. I do not want to have this security problem for my application, so I thought of a ssl decription)

The application is running on a IIS 7.5. Is it possible to have one webapp that has unsecured pages (like the public area) and a secured area (like the member area, which requires a login)? If yes, how can I relealise the communication between these too areas?

**Example**:
My webapp is hosted on  `http://foo.abc`.
I have pages like `http://foo.abc/default.aspx` and `http://foo.abc/foo.aspx`.

In the same project there is a page like `/member/default.aspx` which is protected by a login on the page `http://foo.abc/login.aspx`.

So I would need to implement SSL for the page `/login.aspx` and all pages in `/member/`

How can I do that? I just found out how to create SSL certificates in IIS 7.5 and how to add such a binding to a webapp. How how can I tell my webapp which page should be called with https and not with http. What is the best practise there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here [How to use HTTPS in an ASP.Net Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539732/how-to-use-https-in-asp-net-appllication)

> After you get SSL setup/installed, you
>   want to do some sort of redirect on
>   the login page to https://. Then
>   whatever page the user is sent to
>   after validation, it can just be
>   http://.

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender

    If Request.IsSecureConnection = False And _ 
        Not Request.Url.Host.Contains("localhost") Then 

        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://")) 
    End If  End Sub
```

> This may be easier to implement on a
>   master page or just all the pages you
>   require https. By checking for
>   "localhost" you will avoid getting an
>   error in your testing environment
>   (Unless your test server has another
>   name than check for that:
>   "mytestservername").

Answer (score 3):

I don't work with .net, but we do have websites that have similar setup, where some pages are unencrypted and served using http, and a bunch of pages are served with https instead. Here are some stuff we've done... hope they are helpful.

1. You need to have someway pass the configuration to your code, so it knows the base URI of both the http or https portion. E.g. if your server is foo.bar, you need your code to know that the secure pages are at https://foo.bar:xxx/..., and unsecure pages at http://foo.bar/...
2. You can configure your server with some redirects to make your life easier. E.g. if in your server configs, in the port 80 area, you redirect /xxx to the port 443 /xxx, then in your http pages, you can just use releative URL like /xxx, and not have to include the base URI. Vice versa, you can setup in port 443 config redirecting /yyy to port 80 /yyy, then in your https pages, you can just use relative URL like /yyy
3. Posting between http and https pages: you can't redirect post, so you have to use the base URI for the http or https pages in your form element. I.e. in your http pages, if you post to https, you have to specify the https base URI in the action attribute of the form element -- this is the reason for point 1 above.
4. Obviously both your http and https code should check cookies to determine if a user's logged in, but you want to, in the https pages, check for secure cookies -- those cookies that browser will only send in a https connection.  Your plain-text cookies can get sniffed.
5. AJAX --- this is tricky. You cannot do cross-domain AJAX due to Javascript's security model. So, this means if you are in http, you cannot do AJAX to https, or vice versa; port changes are considered different domains by the browser. There are work-arounds, like using hidden iframes, etc, but those solutions are fairly complex and often have security holes.

Answer (score 2):

Just a word of caution, you shouldn't really use a Self-Signed certificate on a production site.  You ideally should get one from a trusted CA (certificate authority).  The big names are Verisign and Thwate, but there are other, cheaper CA's out there.

If you use a self-signed certificate on a live site, your users will get an ugly warning message asking if they wish to proceed.

In terms of redirecting users to https areas, I usually just forward the pages I want secured (for example, if a user navigates to http://domain.com/login.aspx, I'll immediately redirect the request to https://domain.com/login.aspx (*Response.Redirect(...)*), then take them out of the SSL secured area once they are successfully authenticated.