# How do I make my ASP.NET application serve pages only over HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net, https, web-config

I want my application to serve all of its web pages over SSL, so I added the lines...

```
<secureWebPages enabled="true">
<directory path="." />
</secureWebPages>
```

... to my Web.config and the resulting compiler error is:

> Build (web): Unrecognized configuration section secureWebPages.

I am running Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393114/how-to-secure-login-and-member-area-with-ssl-certificate

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework is the site running on?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you might need to add the appropriate `configSections`...

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- modify as you need. -->
    <section 
        name="secureWebPages" 
        type="Hyper.Web.Security.SecureWebPageSectionHandler, 
        WebPageSecurity" 
        allowLocation="false" />
  </configSections>


   <secureWebPages mode="On" > 
    <directories>
        <add path="/" recurse="True" />
    </directories>
</secureWebPages>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple, quick solution to work for your entire web application, you could add this to the `Application_BeginRequest` method in your `Global.asax` file.

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
...
    If Request.IsSecureConnection = False Then
        Dim ub As New UriBuilder(Request.Url)
        ub.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps
        ub.Port = 443
        Response.Redirect(ub.Uri.ToString, True)
    End If
...
End Sub
```