# Simple but effective security for iOS to ASP.NET JSON service?

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, web-services, security

I am developing an `iPhone application` that GETS data from my `ASP.NET` web service that returns serialized JSON strings.  My method is as follows:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Set GPS Location")]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SetGPS(int userId, double lat, double lng)
{
    ...
    return cord.SerializeToJson();

}
```

Ignoring my temporary anti-pattern of returning a string, what would be a simple, but effective way to provide a security mechanism to ensure that communication between the client and server is secure?

I feel a bit at a loss in my transport to the iPhone and I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS

[How to use HTTPS in an ASP.Net Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539732/how-to-use-https-in-asp-net-appllication)

Comment: Oh, and I'd add a Password or some sort of Session token to your functions args