# Securing Web API /Token Endpoint

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I have a Web API project that follows the basic account authentication process outlined here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api. My question is should I secure the /Token enpoint with SSL (or something else)? Otherwise, the  API call to "myURL/Token" is just sent via clear text with the username and password in its body?

I read up this post on Web API SSL: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api but I don't know where I should place the [RequireHttps] attribute since the /Token endpoint is not really a controller action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTTPS in an ASP.Net Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539732/how-to-use-https-in-an-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should make the Token endpoint as Secure.

In the `Setup.Auth.cs` file under the OAuthurizationServerOptions you can specify to be Token end point requires SSL or not.

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
  {
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
    AllowInsecureHttp = false
  };
```

The `AllowInsecureHttp` will force the url to be SSL or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I must have blind :).