# Using HTTPS ASP.NET web forms application

Tags: asp.net, https

A customer requested that I change the application (ASP.NET web forms) from using HTTP to HTTPS.  They (the customer ID) installed a cert. on the web server.
What do you I need to do now ( in my ASP.NET application ) to make it use  HTTPS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTTPS in an ASP.Net Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539732/how-to-use-https-in-an-asp-net-application)

Comment: Assuming the setup was done properly (you can test by simply loading any page on your site using `https`), this can range from simply changing your links, or handling globally for the entire site. Some [references](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx). Note that depending on the architecture of your site, not all will work nor applicable (e.g. web farms/cloud infrastructures where SSL is offloaded to a load balancer)

Answer (score -3):

You should follow this [blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-ssl-and-how-to-implement-in-Asp-Net-web-aaplication/). There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539732/how-to-use-https-in-an-asp-net-application).

Comment: This is not a good answer for Stack Overflow. If another answer on Stack Overflow answers this question, you should flag this question as a duplicate of that one rather than answering directly.