# Trying to use Https in an ASP Application, What about <html> attribute of `xmlns`

Tags: html, xml, https, xml-namespaces

Trying to use Https in my ASP.Net App, followed those [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539732/how-to-use-https-in-an-asp-net-application).

What about the `html` tag attribute of `xmlns`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
</html>
```

is the url should be with **Https** as well?

like: `xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`?

By the way - is there any update for this xml Namespace (it's from 1999)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `http`: The `xmlns` attribute defines the default namespace. The `http` in its value is a significant part of this identifier. Changing it to `https` would refer to a different namespace not understood by browsers. The same applies to the rest including the `1999` part.

The `xmlns` attribute gives an IRI or URI, see [XML namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) for details. It is just a convention to use a URL linking to information about the namespace. Typically, newer versions of the underlying specification (here [XHTML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/)) only ever get a new identifier if they are incompatible with previous versions. Even the specification for XHTML 1.1 published in 2010 [uses the same namespace identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/conformance.html#s_conform) (with `1999` in it).

You may also want to have a look at [document type declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration) typically used with HTML and XHTML and understood by browsers. If both namespace and document type are used they should match.